# Installing numpy RPM with older Python version

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to install numpy 1.7 via an RPM on an older Linux machine with Python 2.4. The [numpy release notes](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.7.0/) and [the RPM page](http://www.rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/opensuse/factory/i586/python-numpy-1.7.0-2.1.i586.html) say it is supposed to be compatible with 2.4 (or <= 2.7), but when I try to install it on the machine with the command

```
rpm -i /tmp/python-numpy-1.7.0-2.1.i586.rpm
```

I get a number of missing dependency notes, including:

```
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11) is needed by python-numpy-1.7.0-2.1.i586
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) is needed by python-numpy-1.7.0-2.1.i586
    liblapack.so.3 is needed by python-numpy-1.7.0-2.1.i586
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 is needed by python-numpy-1.7.0-2.1.i586
    python >= 2.7 is needed by python-numpy-1.7.0-2.1.i586
    python = 2.7 is needed by python-numpy-1.7.0-2.1.i586
    python(abi) = 2.7 is needed by python-numpy-1.7.0-2.1.i586
    rpmlib(PayloadIsLzma) <= 4.4.6-1 is needed by python-numpy-1.7.0-2.1.i586
```

So now at least Python 2.7 is needed, rather than up to 2.7. Is this a real discrepancy or am I using rpm incorrectly? I'm used to higher-level Linux package managers that report dependencies correctly and install them automatically, so I'm unsure how to proceed here.

Comment: is there a reason you don't want to upgrade to Python 2.7?

Comment: Unfortunately, this machine is one of many at my job and around the world that runs Python 2.4, and I have little power to upgrade them all. (I'm looking into whether it would be practical to put numpy onto them, though would this really be much easier than upgrading Python as well?)

Comment: The NumPy release notes are for the source version. The RPM descr page doesn't say anything about older Python versions. (Note that the PSF has dropped support for Python 2.4, so it's not even getting security fixes anymore.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your distribution does not provide numpy already?  It looks like [numpy](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/repoview/numpy.html) is part of [epel](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

If for some reason you are unwilling to use the version in the distribution, you're likely going to have to build the RPM yourself.  I was able to build 1.7.1 on CentOS 5.7 like so:

```
sudo yum install rpm-build gcc python-devel
wget 'https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.1.tar.gz'
tar -xf numpy-1.7.1.tar.gz 
cd numpy-1.7.1/
python setup.py bdist_rpm
sudo yum localinstall dist/numpy-1.7.1-1.i386.rpm
```

the generated RPM (in `./dist`) should be useable without rebuilding on all of the machines with similar hardware and OS.

Comment: I tried all that, the final install of the rpm fails with the error "Package numpy-1.7.1-1.i386.rpm is not signed".

Comment: then you need to pass `--nogpgcheck` to yum; which will temporarily disable the package signing requirement.

Comment: I got it to work by editing the /etc/yum.conf file; I think the version of yum these machines have predates that option. Is there any reason I can't use the command 'rpm' to install it? (I just tried, it seems to work with no signing hassle)

Comment: The reason to use yum would be to resolve dependencies, it also does some extra work to 'roll back' in case there's an install problem;  in short, yum is less likely to install a broken package into a non-working state.

Answer (score 1):

If all the machines have identical versions of Python, glibc, etc., then it would probably be easier to get the [numpy source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.7.1/) and build it yourself, assuming you have `gcc` (and perhaps `gfortran`) installed, along with dependencies like BLAS and LAPACK. Once it's installed on one machine, you can copy the `numpy` folder (and any `.egg` file) from `/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages` (or whichever directory) and distribute that around the world.  Make sure to create static libraries when you build so you don't need all the dependencies everywhere.

I'd also get numpy 1.7.1, as it fixes some issues with 1.7.0.

Comment: I got it built on one machine using the RPM method given in the other answer. Where should I expect to find these .egg files?

Comment: they should be in the RPM you generated. Once you install the RPM, check the `/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages` directory, and you should find a `numpy/` subdirectory, as well as a a file called `numpy-1.7.1-py2.4.egg-info`. If it's not there, don't worry, your version of Python may not support eggs. Basically, it's just meta-data about the package, very similar to what you'd find on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy)